# Gauge invariant nonlinear functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there a holomorphic nonlinear (not of the form $z\mapsto c z$) function $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ such that 
$$f(e^{is} z) = e^{is}f(z),\quad \forall (s,z)\in \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{C}$$

It's clear that functions of the form $f(z) = |z|^p z, p\neq 0$ satisfy the above property but they are not holomorphic !

Thank you for any hint.

Comment: It is for $p=0$.

Comment: I edited the question !

Comment: How does $z^p$ satisfies your relation?

Comment: for $s \in \mathbb{R,}$ we have $|e^{is}z|^p = |z|^p$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By taking derivatives we get

$f^{(n)}(z)=f^{(n)}(e^{is}z)e^{i(n-1)s}$ for $n \in \mathbb N_0 \setminus\{1\}, s \in \mathbb R$ and $z \in \mathbb C$

Hence, for $n \in \mathbb N_0 \setminus\{1\}$:

$f^{(n)}(0)=f^{(n)}(0)e^{i(n-1)s}$ for all $s \in \mathbb R$ .

Therefore $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for $n \in \mathbb N_0 \setminus\{1\}$. Power series expansion then gives:

$f(z)=cz$ for some $c \in \mathbb C$.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple solution: from $f(e^{is} z) = e^{is}f(z),\quad \forall (s,z)\in \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{C}$ we get, with $z=1$:

$f(w)=f(1)w$ for all $w \in \mathbb C$ with $|w|=1$.

By the identity theorem we derive:

$$f(z)=f(1)z$$

for all $z \in \mathbb C$ .